How to grab every 4 numbers in batch
Working with Windows CMD Batch btw. Anyway, I have a 48 digit long string saved into a variable, and I want to take every 4 digits of that variable and save it into new variables so it can be echoed out.
I want to be able to incremeant the value, and store every 4 digits into new vars like var1=0000 for example.
Also, the string is only numbers.

easy: use a for /L loop and set's ability to extract substrings. Add a counter for the variable names and you're done:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM create a random 48-digit string:
set "string="
for /l %%a in (1,1,48) do set "string=!string!!random:~-1!"
echo 48-digit string: %string%

REM dissect into groups of four and assign to variables:
set count=0
for /l %%a in (0,4,45) do (
  set /a count+=1
  set "var_!count!=!string:~%%a,4!"
)

REM verify output:
set var_

Example output:
48-digit string: 561545587231541933791169318876024486505200864568
var_1=5615
var_10=5052
var_11=0086
var_12=4568
var_2=4558
var_3=7231
var_4=5419
var_5=3379
var_6=1169
var_7=3188
var_8=7602
var_9=4486


This works great in dividing the large number thanks. Few things though, when I try to increment the initial string of 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, it just goes to 1 without all the 0's anyway to fix that?

yes - don't try to use integers (first, it handles numbers starting with zero as octal, second it doesn't do leading zeroes, third, it can't handle numbers that big (INT32 only). Use (the help of) another language (that can handle that issues) or do a strict string processing (pain in the ass, but doable)

So in other words I gotta do it in something like C/C++? Dang alright. You probably already guessed it but yeah I'm trying to make a brute force tool to take Windows BitLocker off. Long story short, trying to undo a stupid "IT's" mistake lol.

I don't know - does C/C++ support that large numbers? If not- you have the same problem (doing "manual math") as in batch. Although it would be MUCH faster in anything but batch.
